# two users auth in a single table in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I'm trying to build an online shop website using laravel framework

I have a table with these column : `id, username, password, division_id`

where `division_id` refers to a table called `division` with: `id, division_type`

and I have two `division type` : `Admin` and `Customers`

I'm trying to divide permission to access a certain number of pages based on their `division_id` such as admin can access Admin panel but not Customer, and customer can access Customer panel such as product-order page but not admin.

Both types can do almost everything in their accessible pages, and my main pages will have an Admin Panel, a customer Panel, and main website.

How can I do that in my project using only a single table and middle-ware group?

P.S. I'm new to this forum

Comment: What is the scenario on relationships? 1 user belongs to only one division? or 1 user belongs to many?

Comment: One user belongs to one Division, One division has many Users.

Comment: the proper way should have two group routes with middleware, for admin and customer

Comment: i'm not really sure how to have more than one group routes , could you show me how with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this Middleware, you just need to check if the `division` required to view the site is the same as the `division` that the user belongs to. In the `handle` function, you can pass a 3rd argument that represents a division name, such as `customer`

When you add the Middleware to your routes, you can pass the name of the division as an argument to the `handle` function like so:

```
'middleware' => ['division:customer']
```

Implementing this in an `Route Group` may look something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer', 'middleware' => ['division:customer']], funtion(){
    //route definitions for all these routes will require a "division" type of "customer"
});
```

Or you could apply it to route resources for `RESTful` routing:

```
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController')->middleware(['divison:customer']);
```

Or you could just apply it to a specific route:

```
Route::get('customer/{id}', 'CustomerController@show')->middleware(['division:customer']);
```

In your `handle` function you can access that value as the 3rd argument:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, Division $division)
```

To make the process of automagically resolving a dependency by something other than the primary key easy, we'll go ahead and pop open our `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` and add some magic inside of the `boot` function.

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->bind('division', function($value) {
        return Division::where(function($query) use($value){
            if (is_int($value)) {
                return $query->where('id', $value)->first();
            } else { 
                return $query->where('type', ucfirst($value))->first();
            }

            return null;
        });
    });
```

Now, back to the Middleware, we can easily make a comparison against the `$division` in our `handle` function, and our `authorized` user.

```
if(app()->user()->division->type == $division->type) {
    return $next($request);
}

abort(403, 'You are not authorized to view this page!');
```

Comment: How do we put  `'middleware' => ['division:customer']`?
Could you show me an example of this implementation in routes.php?

Comment: @Orange You would apply this to your `Routes`. Most probably you want a group. Answer updated.

Comment: Route not found. It's possible for one to pass the `division` parameter to the original `auth` middleware without creating a new middleware?

Comment: @Orange What `route` wasn't found? And you can extend the middleware if you wanted and pass it in yourself, sure.

Comment: Oh , my bad. That was syntax error lol. It worked. Thanks alot!